# Powershell 7 SDK PSCmdlet - difference between GetCmdlet and GetCommand

Tags: powershell, powershell-sdk, powershell-cmdlet

With my first C# based Powershell cmdlet I ran into an issue of how to run "existing" cmdlets from within my custom cmdlet. Along the way I found the following:

```
InvokeCommand.GetCmdlet("Compress-7Zip")
```

and

```
InvokeCommand.GetCommand("Compress-7Zip")
```

1. **Edit** The first returns a CmdletInfo object the second a CommandInfo object
2. GetCmdlet has a description "Returns CmdletInfo object that corresponds to the name argument"
3. GetCommand has no description, but searching on the web I found the following on Mirosoft's website "Activity to invoke the Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Get-Command command in a Workflow"

Why do these two methods exist and which do we use for what?

Answer (score 1):

**Get-Cmdlet** - Returns the CmdletInfo object that corresponds to the **'Name'** argument.

**Get-Command** - gets all commands that are **'Installed'** on the computer, including cmdlets, aliases, functions, filters, scripts, and applications.

**Get-Cmdlet**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandinvocationintrinsics.getcmdlet?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0

**Get-Command**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: Interesting, the method signature for GetCommand in C# provides a parameter of commandName (singular) suggesting a single command and the return type is a CommandInfo object, not a list. Also, your second link refers to Get-Command automatically importing the module if not loaded. My thinking is that Get-Command in this case behaves, or is used, differently from the GetCommand in the SDK?